# can't reach .net core web app using docker (windows)

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core

This is driving me crazy:

I created a new .Net Core Web App from VS2019, adding support for docker (linux containers).
Everything works fine: if I start the debugger from VS the image is built, the container is started and the web app is available at http://localhost:32772/weatherforecast.

Then I clean it all up, and try to build and run manually:

```
docker build -t webapp2 --file webapplication2/Dockerfile .
docker run --name webapp2 -p 5000:5000 -t webapp2
(or even docker run --name webapp2 -p 5000:5000 -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -t webapp2)
```

Build runs successfully, and (apparently) run command works fine too:
[image]
But...surprise...This way I cannot reach the app anymore (at http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast)!

Tried almost anything, use internal ip address from inspect, changing ports and run commands, adding -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80", nothing seems to work.

So the question is: what kind of magic we have behind the VS debug command?

I tried to see what's there but I don't see anything useful:

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\carlo\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Progetti\prove\docker\API\WebApplication2:/app" -v "C:\Progetti\prove\docker\API:/src/" -v "C:\Users\carlo\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -P --name WebApplication2 --entrypoint tail webapplication2:dev -f /dev/null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the port to `docker run` doesn't somehow override the port he application is running on. All you're saying is that you want port 5000 on the container exposed as port 5000 on the network. However, you app is running on 80, so that buys you nothing. You'd need `-p 80:5000`.

The `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable is just way to configure the URLs of your app, which in a container is going to bind to `https://+:443;http://+:80` by default. Setting the environment variable to the same thing again does nothing. You could do something like `http://+:5000`, which would then change the internal port to 5000 instead of 80, and then your original `docker run` command would have worked, because there's something actually running on port 5000.

Comment: Thanks! As usually, the issue was between the chair and the keyboard! So the right command is:  docker run --name webapp2 -p 5001:5001 -t -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5001"  webapp2